# How to display image inside gridview template field without using handler class?

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to display image within template field of the gridview. I want to know how can I pass Image url for the Image control.
This is what I am doing-
ASPX Page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1000px" CellPadding="4" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="122px" 
                                    ImageUrl="" Width="148px" />
                                <br />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="300px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField></asp:GridView>
```

.CS Code:

```
public void show()
{
    try
    {
        dt = g1.return_dt("select * from tbl_item_post where Ref_No is not null order by company");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            pic1 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["image_url"]);
            adsource = new PagedDataSource();
            adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            adsource.PageSize = 10;
            GridView1.DataSource = adsource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please Guide me how to do this.

Comment: didn't any of the answers help ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly bind the image url in the gridview like this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="122px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_url","~/Images/{0}") %>' Width="148px" />
```

You can always able to create the correct url depending upon what values are you saving in the database for the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Eval for DataBinding

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="122px" 
                                ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image_url")%>' Width="148px" />
                            <br />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Since I am saving the files in a folder as well as in the database, in that case it is also necessary to provide folder name along with the eval.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate string and table field using this:

```xml
<ItemTemplate> 
  <asp:Image ID="imgFlag" CssClass="imgright" runat="server" ToolTip="" ImageUrl='<%# "/a_img/a_site/ico16/flag16_"+Eval("doclngid")+ ".gif"  %>'>
</ItemTemplate>
```