# Manage Edits on FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, html, file-upload

I have a product page. I want to add my product to my database and I want also to update my product.
I have a problem with images.
When I insert the product everithing is ok.. In my aspx page I have this code:

```
<span>
  <asp:FileUpload ID="files" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
</span>
<div runat="server" id="previewImages"></div>
```

and when I save my product, in code behind I have this code:

```
string filenm = string.Empty;
HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
       string filename = uploadfile.FileName;
       System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("immScarpe/" + txtStyle.Text));
       file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("immScarpe/" + txtStyle.Text + "/") + fileName);
       //this is pseudo-code
       INSERT INTO PRODUCT_IMM (IdProduct, Path) VALUES (Id, "immScarpe/" + txtStyle.Text + "/" + fileName)
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I can EDIT the saved product. When I click the edit button for a product, I have to load all it's data and let the user modify them. Also the images.

the main question is: How can I load the saved images in asp:FileUpload control?

Another thing I would like to do is to show images previews...in insert and in edit.

An Example of what I want to do is the thing that amazon does
[image]

but, if it's possible with only one FileUpload with AllowMultiple = true

I am willing to use other technologies like javascript, jquery and Ajax if it's necessary

Comment: You don't load the image in the FileUpload control. There is no need for that. You can load the images and show them when edititng. When the user saves the changes, you just check if there are files in the FileUpload. If there are overwrite them. If there are none you just keep the ones you already have.

Comment: @VDWWD: but I would like that the user can see the uploaded images and delete one or more of them. I want to allow the user to replace images and see what he is doing.

Comment: are you able to use GridView or Repeater?

Comment: @CurseStacker if you give me a little example I can try and learn. I know GridViews but not to manage images...

Comment: Are you saving the file in disk and not the database?

Comment: @CurseStacker yes but I can change...

Answer (score 2):

**Show Images Preview - Insert**

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowpImagePreview(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#previewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <asp:Image ID="previewImage" runat="server" />

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="ShowpImagePreview(this);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example as to how you can handle images after they have been send to the server. In this snippet the filename of the image is fixed, but it should be enough to give you push in the right direction.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the file exists and show
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("testImage.jpg")))
    {
        setImage("/testImage.jpg");
    }
}

//upload a new image
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("testImage.jpg"));
            setImage("/testImage.jpg");
        }
        catch
        {
            //error writing file
        }
    }
}

//delete the image
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("testImage.jpg"));
        LinkButton1.Visible = false;
        Image1.Visible = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        //error deleteing file
    }
}

//set the image and show the delete link
private void setImage(string image)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = "/testImage.jpg";
    Image1.Visible = true;
    LinkButton1.Visible = true;
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Delete image</asp:LinkButton>
<br />
<br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: this would be fine but I need to upload more images at a time.

Comment: This is just an example. You can just add as many Controls as you need.

Answer (score 1):

For displaying images to GridView from disk

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-in-GridView-Control-using-the-path-stored-in-SQL-Server-database.aspx

Now you have the images shown, you want to have some replace or delete functionality on the images. You need to convert your field on the GridView for image to Template Field. You can do this by clicking on the source view of your ASPX page and replacing your ImageField or BoundField (whichever field you used in displaying the image).

See the design of the GridView on the question:

[How to display image inside gridview template field without using handler class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741343/how-to-display-image-inside-gridview-template-field-without-using-handler-class)

The way to bind the image source is in the answers in that question.

To have a delete or replace functionality, you can include a LinkButton control inside your TemplateField below the  tag that displays the image.

You can set the LinkButton's CommandName property to 'Delete' or 'Replace' then on your .vb or .cs file, find the 'RowCommand' event for your GridView.

It goes something like (pseudo code only)

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = 'Delete' Then
        'Place your delete query for your image record on the database here..
        'Place your delete file from disk code here..
    End If
End Sub
```

More info on GridView RowCommand Event

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx